# Creating flows in subfolders in apps folder in mule

Tags: maven, mule, config

I have created a flow under a subfolder in src/main/app in mule. So now I have a global folder under src/main/app and I have created a flow in the global folder.

When I do a maven build and run the project I am getting the errores `config for app not found.`

Is there ny work around for this problem,

Note : config.resources gets automatically updated with all .xml file with corresponding sub folders when I do a maven build.

Comment: Can you check if your pom.xml config was able to transfer those in the target folder?

Comment: What do you have in mule-deploy.properties file ?

Comment: @Ralph Rimorin : No its not

Comment: @Mauro Rocco :  Here is the content : redeployment.enabled=true
encoding=UTF-8
domain=default
config.resources=global/shared-resources.xml,test.xml

Comment: Can you extract the generated project.zip in the target folder to see if it transferred the global/shared-resources.xml, just to check if it created the global folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to put a flow in a subfolder under apps like you did but by doubt where confirmed.

When Mule is preparing the zip is not scanning and including the subfolders of /app in the main app folder on deploy but under classes, this causes the error that conf file cannot be found.

At this point if you really want to have flows in subfolder you have only one option:

Move your shared resources flow in `src/main/resources/` for example under a folder `flows`

Add a spring include to your `test.xml` flow in this way

```
<spring:import resource="flows/shared-resources.xml"/>
```

This will include the other flow in your test flow and it will be virtually the same than having them listed in the `mule-deploy.properties`

Note that if your common flow contains logic that could potentially be reused on multiple mule apps you can also put it in a separate mule app that you can package as jar and include as a dependency.
Just google *create mule commons libraries* if you want to know more, I wrote a blog post about it but link it here will look like self promotion.

Hope this helps